# Track .zip Downloads with Piwik

Tags: matomo

I got a little bit of trouble on my website. 
For Tracking the Downloads on our website we use piwik.

Unfortunately Piwik can't track the downloads that are proceed with a Direct Link.

All our downloadable stuff is downloaded on a single click on soundcloud or a shortend link on other social media stuff.

How can i track this downloads with piwik? is it even possible?

Comment: Hi. I have nearly the same problem. Did you solve yours? Regards, Vanessa

Comment: hey @user1099480
i'm sorry, but i couldn't find a solution :/