# Campaign tracking of PDF downloads with piwik

Tags: wordpress, matomo

We are running wordpress and piwik and would like to track direct downloads using campaigns. The problem is close to this one: [Track .zip Downloads with Piwik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550245/track-zip-downloads-with-piwik)

Is there a good way to have a url (with a campaign code) that can be called directly that returns a pdf? What I mean by that is not to access the pdf directly but using a kind of gateway that is tracking the access to the pdf (within the campaign).

Answer (score 0):

I see one possible solution (without gateway):

- In the anchor tag, include directly the css class "piwik_download" and in your href, include the campaign as parameter: "example.pdf?pk_campaign=pdf201707". Full example: `<a href="example.pdf?pk_campaign=pdf201707" class="piwik_download">Download pdf</a>`.

You can find more documentation here: https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#recording-a-click-as-a-download

PS: In case you need a gateway, you could do the same and, track a manual page view event with the JS tracker on the gateway.